# statement and method to update sqlite database

Tags: android-sqlite

I need your help please. I've spent way too much time on this and I can only update the database if I specify the id number.

1. Click listview item and send data to new activity for editing
2. Edit data and return to listview activity.  Simple right. hmmm.

   ```
   @Override  
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {    
   Cursor cursor = (Cursor)listView.getItemAtPosition(position);  
   String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MoviesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));  
   String barcode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MoviesDbAdapter.KEY_BARCODE));   
   String rowId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MoviesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID));

   Intent movieEdit = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MovieEdit.class);  
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
   bundle.putString("rowId", rowId);  
   bundle.putString("title", title);  
   bundle.putString("barcode", barcode);  
   movieEdit.putExtras(bundle);  
   startActivity(movieEdit);
   ```

Receive the intent from the listview activity:

```
if (this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) { 
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras(); 
           editTitle.setText(bundle.getString("title"));     
           editBarcode.setText(bundle.getString("barcode"));
           editId.setText(bundle.getString("rowId"));

          }
```

The statement activated by a button:

```
case R.id.buttonSave:

mDb.open();  
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
values.put(MoviesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE, title);  
values.put(MoviesDbAdapter.KEY_BARCODE, barcode);  
mDb.updateTitle("=?", title, barcode);  
mDb.close();
```

The method in the MovieDbAdapter:

```
public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String title, String barcode)
{  
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();  
args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);  
args.put(KEY_BARCODE, barcode);   
return mDb.update(SQLITE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
```

I know this has been done to death but no matter what I try I just can't update the database with the new data.
Hope you can help guys.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the following

```
case R.id.buttonSave:

    mDb.open();  
    mDb.updateTitle(rowId, title, barcode);  
    mDb.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my query - unfortunately no success. The app doesn't crash or complain but no data is updated  to the database.

Comment: What is the value returned by update statement and also Check whether rowId holds a value before passing and check if the same value exists in the database. if all these are fine and still no success post your code of mDb object's class.

Comment: Okay, I can see the value of rowId passed from ListViewActivity and it matches the value in the database. No errors from logcat and dump of database shows nothing unusual.